# is the tensor product of coordinate rings always a coordinate ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

given an *arbitrary* field $k$ (in particular, it does not need to be algebraically closed or even perfect) and sets $S ⊆ \mathbb A^m(k)$ and $T ⊆ \mathbb A^n(k)$, is there an isomorphism of coordinate rings

$$k[S × T] \cong k[S] \otimes_k k[T]?$$

from the commutative diagram with the natural arrows

$$
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  k[\mathbb A^m × \mathbb A^n] @= k[\mathbb A^m] \otimes_k k[\mathbb A^n] \\
  @VVV @VVV \\
  k[S × T] @<<< k[S] \otimes_k k[T]
 \end{CD}
$$

we would only need a natural arrow in the other direction in the bottom row to conclude that. for this, it would suffice for a regular functions $h \colon \mathbb A^m × \mathbb A^n → k$ vanishing on $S × T$ to come from a sum of products of regular functions $f \colon \mathbb A^m → k$ and $g \colon \mathbb A^n → k$ vanishing on $S$ and $T$ respectively. is that so? how can i show this?

note that i consider *classical* affine space, not schemes and $\mathbb A^m (k) = k^m$ and $\mathbb A^n (k) = k^n$ as sets.

(by the way: i don't see that the tensor product of two reduced $k$-algebras of finite type need not be reduced as an obstruction here as, to my knowledge, the counter-examples arise from inseparable extensions, wich are, to my knowledge, *not* formed by coordinate rings.)

Comment: You need to add a little more information about your setup here - are you working with "classical varieties" or schemes, etc. The answer is a more-or-less obvious yes if you work with schemes, but it looks like you may not be doing that and the answer probably depends on some of the details of your setup.

Comment: yes, classical algebraic loci. i'll add that.

Comment: To be clear, your definition of $k[S]$ is $k[x_1,\dots,x_m]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal of polynomials that vanish on $S$?

Comment: @EricWofsey yeah - is there a different, non-equivalent definition?

Comment: It's clear that $S \times T = V(I(S)+I(T))$, where we used inclusions of the form $k[x_1, \dots, x_m] \hookrightarrow k[x_1, \dots, x_{n+m}]$, so the question reduces to showing that $I(V(I(S)+I(T)))=I(S)+I(T)$. Not sure how to do that, though

Comment: yeah. (well, not quite. i didn’t assume $S$ and $T$ to be closed, so it’s $V(I(S)) × V(I(T)) = V(I(S) + I(T))$ technically speaking, but it reduces to the same question nonetheless.)

Comment: I'd say that if $I(S),I(T)$ are primes it works because $\overline{k}\cap k[S]=k$ so $I(T)(Y)$ remains prime in $k[X,Y]/(I(S)(X))$. Next it is about writing $I(S),I(T)$ as intersection of prime ideals.

Comment: @reuns i can't follow your reasoning here. do you care to elaborate? how do you conclude that $I(T)(Y)$ remains prime in $k[X,Y]/(I(S)(X))$ and how does the assertion then follow?

Answer (score 0):

Functors that have a left adjoint preserve $\underleftarrow{\textrm{lim}}$ (inverse limits), in particular finite products. So perhaps this could (be made to) work.

Let $\mathrm{Aff}_k$ be the category of the algebraic sets $S$ living in some $\mathbb A^m(k)$ (any $m$). Following Hartshorne, regular functions $S\to k$ and morphisms $S\to T$ can be defined just like when $k$ is algebraically closed ([H], §I.3).

Let $_k\mathrm{Fta}$ be the category of $k$-algebras of finite type that are coordinate rings. These can be given as pairs $(n,I)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $k[X_1,\cdots\,X_n]$ which any $f$ $\in$ $k[X_1,\cdots\,X_n]$ that vanishes at all common zeroes in $\mathbb A^n(k)$ of the $i$ $\in$ $I$ must belong to. I.e., we need "$I$ $=$ $I(Z(I))$". Morphisms are $k$-algebra homomorphisms. Denote the opposite category (with all arrows reversed) by $_k\mathrm{Fta}^{\circ}$.

Then we have covariant functors $A:$ $\mathrm{Aff}_k$ $\to$ $_k\mathrm{Fta}^{\circ}$ and $Z:$ $_k\mathrm{Fta}^{\circ}$ $\to\mathrm{Aff}_k$ given, for $S$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb A^m(k)$, by $S$ $\mapsto$ $(m,I(S))$, which is just the $k$-algebra $k[S]$, and by $(n,I)$ $\mapsto$ $\{\vec{\lambda}\in k^n$ $\mid$ $\forall_{i\in I}\,i(\vec{\lambda})=0\}$, which is of course closed.

By corollary I, 3.8 of [H], we have $\mathrm{Aff}_k(Z(n,I),S)$ $\cong$ $_k\mathrm{Fta}^{\circ}(A(Z((n,I))),A(S))$. I think the proof goes through for arbitrary fields $k$. But $A(Z((n,I)))$ $=$ $(n,I)$ because of the restriction we imposed on $I$.

Hence $\mathrm{Aff}_k(Z(n,I),S)$ $\cong$ $_k\mathrm{Fta}^{\circ}((n,I),A(S))$, and these isomorphisms are natural. So $Z\dashv A$, i.e. $Z$ is a left adjoint of $A$, and hence $A$ preserves finite products. Now direct products in $_k\mathrm{Fta}^{\circ}$ are the same thing as direct sums in $_k\mathrm{Fta}$, and those are given, like in the category of all $k$-algebras (for any ring $k$), by $\otimes_k$. So $A(S\times T)$ $\cong$ $A(S)\otimes_kA(T)$.

$A$ also respects any other forms of $\underleftarrow{\textrm{lim}}$ that exist in $\mathrm{Aff}_k$, subject to the fact that all arrows are reversed, so that $A$ will send them to the corresponding $\underrightarrow{\textrm{lim}}$ in $_k\mathrm{Fta}$. So pullbacks become pushouts, etc.

[H] Robin Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*.

Comment: How do you know that coproducts in $_k\mathrm{Fta}$ are given by $\otimes_k$?

Comment: Haha, you are right. That is precisely the original question! Coproducts exist ($A$ produces them), but they may not necessarily be given by the tensor product (which needs not be in $_k\mathrm{Fta}$). Also, if the argument had worked, there should have been an easy direct proof avoiding category theory.